# Getting SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found even after installing dependencies

Tags: java, maven, slf4j

My Class

```java
package com.logging.slf4j;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Main {
    static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.warn("Hello");
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.logging</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-reload4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-reload4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I have all the maven dependencies are installed.
[image]

Still i am having the following error..

```java
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing the scope(as per previous answer) log4j.properties should configured properly and place should be src/main/resources.

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. It is not mentioned where the property file is located

Answer (score 2):

remove the `<scope>test</scope>` from the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-reload4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.6</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

if you want to use it in running code.

Libraries with scope `test` are only available in unit tests